# Indeterminate sort ordering - MySQL vs Postgres

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I have the following query

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_1 
INNER JOIN table_2 ON table_1.orders = table_2.orders 
ORDER BY table_2.purchasetime;
```

The above query result is indeterminate i.e it can change with different queries when the purchase time is of same value as per the MySQL manual itself.To overcome this we give sort ordering on a unique column and combine it with the regular sort ordering.

The customer does not want to see different results with different page refreshes so we have put in the above fix specifically for MySQL which is unnecessary and needs extra compound indexes for both asc and desc.

I am not sure whether the same is applicable for postgres.So far I have not been able to reproduce the scenario.I would appreciate if someone could answer this for postgres or point me in the right direction.

**Edit 1** : The sort column is indexed.So assuming the disk data has no ordering, but in the case of index (btree data structure) a constant ordering might be possible with postgres ?

Comment: SQL is a declarative language. You tell the system *what you want*. The server is free to return the result in *any* order that happens to work, provided it matches the specification you gave it. So, if you want results in a particular order, make sure that you've *specified* that order, completely, in your `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever : Please see my query above, I have given the Order By, the problem is indeterminate results when the order by column has same data.

Comment: Yes, so you've not been *specific* enough with your `ORDER BY` conditions. That's the point I'm making. `ORDER BY` is the one place where you get to tell the server "this is the order that I need for my results".

Comment: Oh.I get it now, but I can understand this in a situation where indexes are not present.But can a btree index provide constant sort ordering ?

Comment: I'm not sure how else to say it. You have one mechanism by which you can tell the system "these are the ordering guarantees I want". That is the `ORDER BY` clause. So, just go ahead and give the specification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it will not be different in PostgreSQL (or, in fact, in any other relational database that I know of).

See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/queries-order.html :

> After a query has produced an output table (after the select list has been processed) it can optionally be sorted. If sorting is not chosen, the rows will be returned in an unspecified order. **The actual order in that case will depend on the scan and join plan types and the order on disk, but it must not be relied on**. A particular output ordering can only be guaranteed if the sort step is explicitly chosen.

Even if by accident you manage to find a PostgreSQL version and index that will guarantee the order in all the test you run, *please don't rely on it*. Any database upgrade, data change or a change in the Maya calendar or the phase of the moon can suddenly upset your sorting order. And debugging it then is a true and terrible pain in the neck.

Comment: Exactly. This looks stable at the moment because of plan choice etc, but the statistics-driven cost-based planner may select a different plan when the data grows, its distribution changes, etc, and the new plan might use join methods, aggregation methods etc that are not stable in ordering. Use a specific sort key.

Answer (score 1):

Your concern seems to be that `order by table_2.purchasetime` is indeterminate when there are multiple rows with the same value.

To fix this -- in any database or really any computer language -- you need a stable sort.  You can turn any sort into a stable sort by adding a unique key.  So, adding a unique column (typically an id of some sort) fixes this in both MySQL and Postgres (and any other database).

I should note that instability in sorts can be a very subtle problem, one that only shows up under certain circumstances.  So, you could run the same query many times and it is fine.  Then you insert or delete a record (perhaps even one not chosen by the query) and the order changes.

Comment: A unique column is already available as I said above, but the problem with that approach is there are extra compound indexes required i.e one for asc and another for desc.I agree that indeterminate sorting occurs since data is scattered across the disk, but in the case of a btree data structure I was thinking that somehow this problem might not pop up in postgres